# Mark row red if less than 5 occurrences per month

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I was using a conditional formatting to mark the whole row blue if there is a "VISA" transaction in column E.

Would it be possible to set up a conditional formatting to mark the VISA transactions rows red if there is less than 5 of them in each month?
I can't make the formula work it out automatically...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select A:E, clear any existing CF from it, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND($E1="VISA",COUNTIFS($E:$E,"VISA",$A:$A,">"&EOMONTH($A1,-1),$A:$A,"<"&EOMONTH($A1,0)+1)<5)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red font, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Reinstate other CF to suit.

Comment: Amazing, that did it... but I didn't imagine, how much the calculation slows down the worksheet upon each new input... even when I limited the range of the CF down to only first 200 rows :(